# How to recover Google account if you lose your phone number?

Tags: gmail, google-account, account-recovery

I tried to log in to my Google account but after typing in the correct email and password, Google demands me to enter SMS code sent to my phone number attached to the account. However, I already lost the phone number, which I was using while living in another country. There is no way to recover the same phone number from the operator.

So I chose "try another way", which has four options - "get a verification code at ***", "call your phone on file ***", "get help" and "can't use your phone?". I couldn't use the first two choices as I have no phone number. The fourth choice always gets me to the "use phone" page. If I chose the third choice, it forces me to type in the "Enter the last password you remember using with this Google Account", where I typed in the correct password. However, the screen always shows:

> You didn't provide enough info for Google to be sure this account is really yours. Google asks for this info to keep your account secure.

> To recover your account, try again and answer each question shown.

However, no matter how many times I tried the same step, it only asked me the same question - type in the last used password. I saved it both to iCloud Keychain and 1Password, so it must be the correct password, but Google still says they can't be sure if the account is mine.

There is no section that enters the email or phone number that lets Google reach me, [as written here](https://support.google.com/accounts/answer/185834?hl=en).

So how can I recover the account?

---

#### UPDATE

There is no such option as *Verify your identity* as suggested in the accepted answer that is attached to the duplicate question.

Comment: You could appeal that this question be reopened or ask for a discussion about the closing of this question at [meta].